# Update Data in a MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to update data, like a weight (`2.150Kg`), in a MySQL database.

This is the code I used in NetBeans:

```
  connectDB();
    try{

        String value1 = txt_search_code.getText();
        String value2 = txt_item_code.getText();
        String value3 = txt_discription.getText();
        String value4 = txt_bin_balance.getText();
        String value5 = txt_date.getText();
        String value6 = txt_issued_quantaty.getText();
        String value7 = txt_issued_inno.getText();
        String value8 = txt_arrived_quantaty.getText();
        String value9 = txt_arrived_inno.getText();
        String value10 = txt_final_bin_balance.getText();

        String sql = "Update tbl_codes set No='"+value1+"',ITEM_CODE='"+value2+"',DISCRIPTION='"+value3+"',PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE='"+value4+
                     "',DATE='"+value5+"',ISSUED_QUANTATY='"+value6+"',ISSUED_INVOICE_NO='"+value7+"',ARRIVED_QUANTATY='"+value8+"',ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO='"+value9+"',FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE='"+value10+"'WHERE No='"+value1+"' ";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your new records Updated Succsessfully!!");

    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

    closeDB();
```

This is the SQL update statement:

```
SELECT
`tbl_stock`.`No`,
`tbl_stock`.`ITEM_CODE`,
`tbl_stock`.`DISCRIPTION`,
`tbl_stock`.`PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE`,
`tbl_stock`.`DATE`,
`tbl_stock`.`ISSUED_QUANTATY`,
`tbl_stock`.`ISSUED_INVOICE_NO`,
`tbl_stock`.`ARRIVED_QUANTATY`,
`tbl_stock`.`ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO`,
`tbl_stock`.`FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE`
FROM `db_biling`.`tbl_stock`;
```

How can I update the weight?

Comment: What is your database name ? Since all the data are in same table, you don't need to create `tbl_stock`

Comment: Any message from 'JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()`. But your code need to refine a lot. Check my sample code

```
String sql = "Update tbl_codes set No= ?,ITEM_CODE=?,DISCRIPTION=?,PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE=?
                    ,DATE=?,ISSUED_QUANTATY=?,ISSUED_INVOICE_NO=?,ARRIVED_QUANTATY=?,ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO=?,FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE=? WHERE No=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, value1);
pstmt.setString(2, value2);
pstmt.setString(3, value3);
pstmt.setString(4, value4);
pstmt.setString(5, value5);
pstmt.setString(6, value6);
pstmt.setString(7, value7);
pstmt.setString(8, value8);
pstmt.setString(9, value9);
pstmt.setString(10, value10);
pstmt.setString(11, value1);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

If you use `PreparedStatement`, use `?` instead of concatenating values into the SQL, like `'"+value1+"'`. Using `?` is more clear and more secure.